# Pass cookie through tomcat proxy from Apache

Tags: apache, tomcat, cookies, proxy

I have an application server that I proxy requests to, from Apache. I also have a Tomcat context that I proxy requests to, from Apache. Sometimes, I proxy a request to the Tomcat context, and then that context makes a request to the app server, which tries to read a cookie.

The bottom line is that the app server tries to read a cookie from the client. This is fine when the request is coming from Apache, but not when the request is proxied *through* Tomcat.

I have these rules set up:

```
ProxyPass /tomcat_context/ http://mydomain:8080/tomcat_context/
ProxyPassReverse /tomcat_context/ http://mydomain:8080/tomcat_context/ 
ProxyPassReverseCookiePath /tomcat_context/ http://mydomain:8080/tomcat_context/

ProxyPass /app/ http://myappbox.com/app/
```

The app server isn't seeing the cookies when the request comes in through the Tomcat context.

I may just be thinking about this the wrong way, or there may be something I'm missing. Thanks for your help, in advance.

Comment: the cookies you're looking for are such that the browser knows of? Are they for myappbox.com/app or are they for mydomain/tomcat_context? If they're for the first, then it's not a miracle that tomcat won't see them

Comment: So you have Tomcat making a loopback request (or something similar)? How are you making that request from Tomcat back to Tomcat? Do you use a library (e.g. Apache Commons HttpClient) or do you use `java.net.HttpURLConnection`, or did you roll your own from some other component? If you want to accept a request from the client and then masquerade as that client when making a loopback connection, you'll have to copy the cookie from the client request to the request you are making internally.